# Solving for multi-variable functions

Tags: functions

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial of $x,y$ satisfying

$(i) f(1,2) = 2$

$(ii) yf(x,f(x,y)) = xf(f(x,y), y) = (f(x,y))^2$.

Determine all such $f(x,y)$.

I don't even know where to start on this one. Substituting arbitrary values for $x$ and $y$ haphazardly hasn't lead to anywhere meaningful. If anyone could share their though process in attacking this problem it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you don't want to guess the answer you can do the following:

The solution has to be some polynomial $f(x,y)$ of finite degree. Suppose it is
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n c_{ij} x^i y^j
$$ 
and some unknown coefficients $c_{ij}$.

The maximum degree in $x$ and $y$ would be $m$ and $n$ respectively. Inserting this into the given relations you can find out what the maximum exponent of $x$ and $y$ can be. 
$$
y f(x,f(x,y)) \rightarrow y f(x, [x^m y^n]) \rightarrow y x^m [x^m y^n]^n \rightarrow x^{m+m n} y^{n^2+1}
$$
$$
x f(f(x,y),y) \rightarrow x f([x^m y^n],y) \rightarrow x [x^m y^n]^m y^n \rightarrow x^{m^2+1} y^{n+m n}
$$
$$
 (f(x,y))^2 \rightarrow [x^m y^n]^2 \rightarrow x^{2 m} y^{2 n}
$$
These are the "worst case" scenarios, if all $c_{ij} \neq 0$.

We know that $m$ is the maximum exponent of $x$ and there is some term $x^m y^j$ with $j \leq n$. The maximum power in $x$ in the third expression $f(x,y)$ is therefore $2 m$. The first expression tells us that $m + m n$ is the maximum that could appear, and hence we have $ m + m n \leq 2 m$. This implies $n \leq 1$.

A similar argument on powers of $y$ , provides $n+m n\leq 2n$. It therefore follows that $m,n \leq 1$ and that the function can only be of the form:
$$
f(x,y) = c_{0,0} + c_{1,0} x + c_{0,1} y + c_{1,1} x y
$$

This we can insert in the relations and solve for the coefficients $c_{ij}$ or we take the short-cut and observe that the first term in the relation contains a factor $x$ and the second term a factor $y$. Therefore every term in $f(x,y)^2$ must contain a factor $xy$ and hence $c_{0,0}=c_{1,0}=c_{0,1}=0$.

This leaves $f(x,y) = c_{2,2} x y$ which, if we use the first requirement, gives us that there is only one solution $f(x,y)=x y$

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by substituting $x=1,y=2$ we get $f(2,2)=4$. Now put $x=2,y=2$ & we get $f(2,4)=f(4,2)=8$.
Continuing with $x=2^n,y=2$ it is easily shown by induction that $f(2^n,2)=2^{n+1}$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,2)=2x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Using a similar argument we can show that $f(2,y)=2y$ & so 
it is obvious that the solution is $\color{red}{f(x,y)=xy}$. It is easy to show that this satisfies the given equations.

Comment: How can you prove that $f(x,y) = xy$ is a unique solution? Or if there are other solutions?

Comment: @DZhao Ronald's answer neatly addresses the issue of uniqueness & I will not be able to improve on his argument. He deserves the up tick from you.